# onClick working only for one time

Tags: android

This is the signUp activity I'm trying to create where user inputs username, emailID and password. The problem that is occuring is that onClick() is working only for once. Suppose password and confirmPassword doesn't matches then textlayout shows the message but if it again doesn't matches then nothing happens. Please help me where I'm going wrong.

```
public class SignUp extends AppCompatActivity {

// will send the data into database and return to the login page with a confirm signup message

private final AppCompatActivity activity = SignUp.this;
TextInputEditText usernameText,emailIdText,passwordText,confirmPasswordText;
NestedScrollView nestedScrollView;
TextInputLayout usernameTextLayout, emailIdTextLayout, passwordTextLayout, confirmPasswordTextLayout;
DatabaseManager manager ;
ErrorsHelper helper;
Students student;


@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.sign_up);
    initViews();
    initObjects();
}

//views initializer 
public void initViews(){

    nestedScrollView = (NestedScrollView)findViewById(R.id.signUpNestedScrollView);

    // Text Input Layout views
    usernameTextLayout = (TextInputLayout) findViewById(R.id.usernameTextLayout);
    emailIdTextLayout = (TextInputLayout) findViewById(R.id.emailIdTextLayout);
    passwordTextLayout = (TextInputLayout) findViewById(R.id.passwordTextLayout);
    confirmPasswordTextLayout = (TextInputLayout) findViewById(R.id.confirmPasswordTextLayout);

    // Text Input views
    usernameText = (TextInputEditText)findViewById(R.id.usernameText);
    emailIdText = (TextInputEditText)findViewById(R.id.emailIdText);
    passwordText = (TextInputEditText)findViewById(R.id.passwordText);
    confirmPasswordText = (TextInputEditText)findViewById(R.id.confirmPasswordText);
}

// objects initializer
public void initObjects(){
    helper = new ErrorsHelper(activity);
    manager = new DatabaseManager(activity);
    student = new Students();

}

//Register Button
public void onClick(View view){

    if(!helper.emptyTextField(usernameText,usernameTextLayout,"Please enter username.")){
        return;
    }
    if(!helper.emptyTextField(emailIdText,emailIdTextLayout,"Please enter email-id.")){
        return;
    }
    if(!helper.emptyTextField(passwordText,passwordTextLayout,"Please enter password.")){
        return;
    }
    if(!helper.emptyTextField(confirmPasswordText,confirmPasswordTextLayout,"Please enter your password to confirm.")){
        return;
    }
    if(!helper.passwordConfirm(passwordText,confirmPasswordText,confirmPasswordTextLayout,"Confirm password doesn't match!")){
        return;
    }
    String username = usernameText.getText().toString();
    String emailId = emailIdText.getText().toString();
    String confirmPassword = confirmPasswordText.getText().toString();
    if (manager.checkUsernameExistence(username)) {
        student.set_username(username);
        student.set_emailid(emailId);
        student.set_password(confirmPassword);
        //add student
        manager.addStudent(student);

        Snackbar.make(nestedScrollView,"Registration Successful.",Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Intent intent = new Intent(this,SignInMainPage.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
   else{
        helper.userExists(usernameTextLayout,"Username already exists.");
    }
}
}
```

ErrorHelper class helps to maintain all the error based things at one place.Also, Snackbar is not showing up.

```
public class ErrorsHelper {

Context context;

public ErrorsHelper(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
}

public boolean emptyTextField(TextInputEditText editText, TextInputLayout inputLayout, String errorMessage) {
    String value = editText.getText().toString().trim();
    if (value.isEmpty()) {
        inputLayout.setError(errorMessage);
        hideKeyboardFrom(editText);
        return false;
    } else {
        inputLayout.setErrorEnabled(false);
    }

    return true;
}

;

public boolean passwordConfirm(TextInputEditText password, TextInputEditText confirmPassword, TextInputLayout confirmPasswordLayout, String errorMessage) {

    String pass = password.getText().toString();
    String cPass = confirmPassword.getText().toString();
    if (pass != cPass) {
        confirmPasswordLayout.setError(errorMessage);
        return false;
    } else {
        confirmPasswordLayout.setErrorEnabled(false);
    }
    return true;
}

private void hideKeyboardFrom(View view) {
    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) context.getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
}

public void userExists( TextInputLayout confirmPasswordLayout, String errorMessage){
    confirmPasswordLayout.setError(errorMessage);
}
```

}

This is the XML layout file for my SignUp page

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/signUpNestedScrollView"
android:paddingTop="100dp">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/signUpLinearLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/usernameTextLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center">
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
    android:id="@+id/usernameText"
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
    android:hint="Username here"
    android:fontFamily="casual"/>
</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/emailIdTextLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center">

<android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
    android:id="@+id/emailIdText"
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:hint="Email-ID here"
    android:fontFamily="casual"/>
</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/passwordTextLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center">

<android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
    android:id="@+id/passwordText"
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:hint="Password"
    android:inputType="textPassword"
    android:fontFamily="casual"/>
</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/confirmPasswordTextLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center">

<android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
    android:id="@+id/confirmPasswordText"
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:hint="Confirm Password"
    android:inputType="textPassword"
    android:fontFamily="casual"/>
</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/signupButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:fontFamily="casual"
    android:onClick="onClick"
    android:text="Sign-Up"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:layout_gravity="center"/>

</LinearLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Comment: how do you add onclick listener to the button i dont see in the code

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add my XML layout file, I've declared onClick through XML

Answer (score 0):

```
    public void onClick(View view){

        // they should be here
            String username = usernameText.getText().toString();
            String emailId = emailIdText.getText().toString();
            String confirmPassword = confirmPasswordText.getText().toString();

        if(!username.isEmpty()&&!emailId.isEmpty()&&!confirmPassword.isEmpty())
        {    
            if(!helper.emptyTextField(usernameText,usernameTextLayout,"Please enter username.")){
                return;
            }
            if(!helper.emptyTextField(emailIdText,emailIdTextLayout,"Please enter email-id.")){
                return;
            }
            if(!helper.emptyTextField(passwordText,passwordTextLayout,"Please enter password.")){
                return;
            }
            if(!helper.emptyTextField(confirmPasswordText,confirmPasswordTextLayout,"Please enter your password to confirm.")){
                return;
            }
            if(!helper.passwordConfirm(passwordText,confirmPasswordText,confirmPasswordTextLayout,"Confirm password doesn't match!")){
                return;
            }

            if (manager.checkUsernameExistence(username)) {
                student.set_username(username);
                student.set_emailid(emailId);
                student.set_password(confirmPassword);
                //add student
                manager.addStudent(student);


                //Snackbar.make(findViewById(android.R.id.content),"Registration Successful.",Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Snackbar s = Snackbar.make(findViewById(android.R.id.content),"Registration Successful.",Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
                s.show();
                Intent intent = new Intent(this,SignInMainPage.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
           else{
                helper.userExists(usernameTextLayout,"Username already exists.");
            }
        }
        else
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext,"Empty",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show;

    }
```

Comment: do it manually cast button with id and then button.setOnClickListener....